# Como remover o espaçamento gerado pela tag a?

Tags: css

Quando insiro a tag `a` para linkar o `img`, gera um espaço na parte inferior das imagens. Veja a imagem abaixo!

Embora o espaço seja pequeno, ele é bem chato não saber como resolver:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que o link não gere este espaçamento.

**HTML**

```
<section class="compartilhar">

<figure>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br" title="Compartilhar no Facebook">
    <img src="./imagens/compartilhar-face.png">
    </a>
</figure>

<figure>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br&text=Guarapari%20Virtual" title="Compartilhar no Twitter">
    <img src="./imagens/compartilhar-gplus.png">
    </a>
</figure>

<figure>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br" title="Compartilhar no Goole Plus">
    <img src="./imagens/compartilhar-twitter.png">
    </a>
</figure>

<figure>
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br&title=Guarapari%20Virtual" title="Compartilhar no LinkEdin">
    <img src="./imagens/compartilhar-linkedin.png">
    </a>
</figure>

<figure>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br" title="Compartilhar no Tumblr">
    <img src="./imagens/compartilhar-tumblr.png">
    </a>
</figure>

<figure>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br" title="Compartilhar no Pinterest">
    <img src="./imagens/compartilhar-pinterest.png">
    </a>
</figure>

</section>
```

**CSS**

```
section.compartilhar{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #D6E6F0;
}

section.compartilhar figure{
  width: 16.66666666666667%;
}

section.compartilhar figure img{
  max-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar tudo na mesma linha? Geralmente é isso!

Comment: @dipievil fiz conforme me falou, mas não funcionou!

Comment: Inspecionando no browser você já conseguiu identificar aonde está o espaço (no a, no href, etc)?

Comment: @dipievil percebi que é no `a`

Comment: Então cria uma classe e adiciona para o "a" com padding:0px ;)

Comment: Se nada do que te sugeriram funcionar, tenta colocar isto no seu CSS: `a { line-height: 0; }`

Comment: Já parou pra pensar que pode ser um espaçamento na própria imagem? Uma dica simples e que abre portas para desenvolver: Quando o assunto é ícone, procure não utilizar imagens como você está fazendo ai. Porque? Imagens podem estourar a resolução dependendo do tamanho da tela e não são preparadas para todo tipo de resolução. Existe solução? Claro que sim! Dê uma olhada neste site e se surpreenda com a quantidade de ícones(em formato de fonte) disponíveis gratuitamente e que nunca irão perder 1px se quer de resolução (http://fontawesome.io/icons/)

Answer (score -2):

Tenta adicionar uma classe com **margin** e **padding** zerados. Talvez utilizando um *!important*.

https://jsfiddle.net/09mdbc4g/

Answer (score -2):

Tanto a tag `a` quanto `img` são, por padrão, elementos "em linha", isto é, recebem `display: inline`, portanto, eles recebem uma altura de linha como se fosse um texto comum.

Uma solução pode ser colocar nos dois `line-height: 0`, mas a melhor solução global é usar `display: block` ou `display: inline-block`.